# How to get data from react query "useQuery" hook in a specific type

Tags: react-query

When we get data from useQuery hook, I need to parse the data a specific type before it return to user. I want data which return from useQuery hook should be of "MyType" using the parsing function i created below. I am unable to find method to use my parsing function. Is there any way to do it? I don't want to rely on schema structure for data type.

```js
type MyType = {
id: number;
//some more properties
}

function parseData(arr: any[]): MyType[]{
  return arr.map((obj, index)=>{
    return {
      id: arr.id,
      //some more properties
    }
  })
}

const {data} = await useQuery('fetchMyData', async ()=>{
    return await axios.get('https://fake-domain.com')
  }
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take the response from the api and transform it inside the queryFn, before you return it to react-query. Whatever you return winds up in the query cache, so:

```
const { data } = await useQuery('fetchMyData', async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://fake-domain.com')
    return parseData(response.data)
  }
)
```

`data` returned from `useQuery` should then be of type `MyType[] | undefined`

There are a bunch of other options to do data transformation as well, and I've written about them here:

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own hook and perform normalisation there:

```
const useParseData = () => {
 const { data } = await useQuery('fetchMyData', async () => {
    return await axios.get('https://fake-domain.com')
 }
 
 return parseData(data)  
}
```

And where you need this data you could just call `const parsedData = useParseData()`